# java.util.Date format conversion yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a `java.util.Date` in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I want it to be in the format `mm-dd-yyyy`

Below is the sample util I tried out for this conversion:

```
// Setting the pattern
SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
// myDate is the java.util.Date in yyyy-mm-dd format
// Converting it into String using formatter
String strDate = sm.format(myDate);
//Converting the String back to java.util.Date
Date dt = sm.parse(strDate);
```

Still the output I am getting is not in the format `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Kindly let me know how to format a `java.util.Date` from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: What do you mean when you say.. I have a java.util.Date in the format yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: It means the present format in my code for displaying it to UI is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: please change small mm to MM

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`Date` is a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch ( 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970).

It has no concept of format.

## Java 8+

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(ldt));
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(ldt));
System.out.println(ldt);
```

Outputs...

```
05-11-2018
2018-05-11
2018-05-11T17:24:42.980
```

## Java 7-

You should be making use of the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

## Original Answer

For example...

```
Date myDate = new Date();
System.out.println(myDate);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(myDate));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myDate));
System.out.println(myDate);
```

Outputs...

```
Wed Aug 28 16:20:39 EST 2013
08-28-2013
2013-08-28
Wed Aug 28 16:20:39 EST 2013
```

None of the formatting has changed the underlying `Date` value.  This is the purpose of the `DateFormatter`s

**Updated with additional example**

Just in case the first example didn't make sense...

This example uses two formatters to format the same date.  I then use these same formatters to parse the `String` values back to `Date`s.  The resulting parse does not alter the way `Date` reports it's value.

`Date#toString` is just a dump of it's contents.  You can't change this, but you can format the `Date` object any way you like

```
try {
    Date myDate = new Date();
    System.out.println(myDate);

    SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat dmyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    // Format the date to Strings
    String mdy = mdyFormat.format(myDate);
    String dmy = dmyFormat.format(myDate);

    // Results...
    System.out.println(mdy);
    System.out.println(dmy);
    // Parse the Strings back to dates
    // Note, the formats don't "stick" with the Date value
    System.out.println(mdyFormat.parse(mdy));
    System.out.println(dmyFormat.parse(dmy));
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Wed Aug 28 16:24:54 EST 2013
08-28-2013
2013-08-28
Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 EST 2013
Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Also, be careful of the format patterns.  Take a closer look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to make sure you're not using the wrong patterns ;)

Comment: Great answer helped me.  Was trying to run a command-line sample app to test formats (before using in an Android class) -- couldn't find the import I needed. None of the provided answers remember to include that : import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Comment: I may be wrong but the naming of  SimpleDateFormat dmyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
is wrong. It should be ymdFormat.

Comment: @RudyVissers That would depend on what you want to achieve.  The question explicitly states `yyyy-MM-dd` is the input format - but the actual problem is - `Date` or `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` or `Calendar` don't actually have an intrinsic format, they are agnostic containers, so you need to "apply" a format to them - you may find that the actual format used for `toString` changes based on the configured locale, which is another reason to use a formatter anyway

Answer (score 36):

```
SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
```

because `MM points Month`, `mm points minutes`

```
SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String strDate = sm.format(myDate);
```

Comment: Apart from this change, any other change i need to make in the above util method? I am not able to test it right away, hence asking this. ALso, is there any better way for formatting the `java.util.Date` ?

Answer (score 15):

'M' (Capital) represent month & 'm' (Simple) represent minutes

Some example for months

```
'M' -> 7  (without prefix 0 if it is single digit)
'M' -> 12

'MM' -> 07 (with prefix 0 if it is single digit)
'MM' -> 12

'MMM' -> Jul (display with 3 character)

'MMMM' -> December (display with full name)
```

Some example for minutes

```
'm' -> 3  (without prefix 0 if it is single digit)
'm' -> 19
'mm' -> 03 (with prefix 0 if it is single digit)
'mm' -> 19
```

Answer (score 5):

Please change small "mm" month to capital "MM" it will work.for reference below is the sample code.

```
        Date myDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
       
        String strDate = sm.format(myDate);
        
        Date dt = sm.parse(strDate);
        System.out.println(strDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "01-23-2017" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" )
)
```

## Details

> I have a java.util.Date in the format yyyy-mm-dd

As other mentioned, the `Date` class has no format. It has a count of milliseconds since the start of 1970 in UTC. No strings attached.

## java.time

The other Answers use troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

If you have a `java.util.Date`, convert to a `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

## Time zone

The other Answers ignore the crucial issue of time zone. Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. A few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day, while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

Define the time zone by which you want context for your `Instant`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

Apply the `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

## `LocalDate`

If you only care about the date without a time-of-day, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD, simply call `toString`. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when generating/parsing strings.

```
String output = localDate.toString();
```

> 2017-01-23

If you want a MM-DD-YYYY format, define a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" );
String output = localDate.format( f );
```

Note that the formatting pattern codes are case-sensitive. The code in the Question incorrectly used `mm` (minute of hour) rather than `MM` (month of year).

Use the same `DateTimeFormatter` object for parsing. The java.time classes are thread-safe, so you can keep this object around and reuse it repeatedly even across threads.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "01-23-2017" , f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is simple use below codes.

```
final Date todayDate = new Date();

System.out.println(todayDate);

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(todayDate));

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(todayDate));

System.out.println(todayDate);
```

Comment: (A) This code ignores the crucial issue of time zones. (B) This code uses troublesome old date-time classes that have been legacy for years now. Avoid them. Supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

You may get day, month and year and may concatenate them or may use MM-dd-yyyy format as given below.

```
Date date1 = new Date();
String mmddyyyy1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(date1);
System.out.println("Formatted Date 1: " + mmddyyyy1);



Date date2 = new Date();
Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar1.setTime(date2);
int day1   = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // {0 - 11}
int year1  = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String mmddyyyy2 = ((month1<10)?"0"+month1:month1) + "-" + ((day1<10)?"0"+day1:day1) + "-" + (year1);
System.out.println("Formatted Date 2: " + mmddyyyy2);



LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.now();  
DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");  
String mmddyyyy3 = ldt1.format(format1);  
System.out.println("Formatted Date 3: " + mmddyyyy3);  



LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.now();
int day2 = ldt2.getDayOfMonth();
int mont2= ldt2.getMonthValue();
int year2= ldt2.getYear();
String mmddyyyy4 = ((mont2<10)?"0"+mont2:mont2) + "-" + ((day2<10)?"0"+day2:day2) + "-" + (year2);
System.out.println("Formatted Date 4: " + mmddyyyy4);



LocalDateTime ldt3 = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 6, 11, 14, 30); // int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute
DateTimeFormatter format2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");  
String mmddyyyy5 = ldt3.format(format2);   
System.out.println("Formatted Date 5: " + mmddyyyy5); 



Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar2.setTime(new Date());
int day3  = calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // OR Calendar.DATE
int month3= calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year3 = calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String mmddyyyy6 = ((month3<10)?"0"+month3:month3) + "-" + ((day3<10)?"0"+day3:day3) + "-" + (year3);
System.out.println("Formatted Date 6: " + mmddyyyy6);



Date date3 = new Date();
LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date3)); // Accepts only yyyy-MM-dd
int day4  = ld1.getDayOfMonth();
int month4= ld1.getMonthValue();
int year4 = ld1.getYear();
String mmddyyyy7 = ((month4<10)?"0"+month4:month4) + "-" + ((day4<10)?"0"+day4:day4) + "-" + (year4);
System.out.println("Formatted Date 7: " + mmddyyyy7);



Date date4 = new Date();
int day5   = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date4)).getDayOfMonth();
int month5 = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date4)).getMonthValue();
int year5  = LocalDate.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date4)).getYear();
String mmddyyyy8 = ((month5<10)?"0"+month5:month5) + "-" + ((day5<10)?"0"+day5:day5) + "-" + (year5);
System.out.println("Formatted Date 8: " + mmddyyyy8);



Date date5 = new Date();
int day6   = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(date5));
int month6 = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(date5));
int year6  = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date5));
String mmddyyyy9 = ((month6<10)?"0"+month6:month6) + "-" + ((day6<10)?"0"+day6:day6) + "-" + (year6);`enter code here`
System.out.println("Formatted Date 9: " + mmddyyyy9);
```

Answer (score 0):

see these..

formatting date

[DateTimeFormatter](https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/)

parsing date

[Instant with zone](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/)