# Printing date using dateformat is different when setting own date or when calling new Date ()

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to print two dates using SimpleDateFormat but for my custom date the output looks completely different.

```
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date2 =dateFormat.parse("01/01/2014 10:45:01");
    System.out.println(("date2:"+date2));
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); // how it prints this  is the desired outcome
```

OUTPUT:

```
date2:Wed Jan 01 10:45:01 GMT 2014
11/04/2014 10:45:50
```

Comment: Date has no concept of a format, it is simply a container of the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. It has a human readable output simply for convince. If you want to change how a date value looks, you need to pass it through a formatter and store the resulting String value for your own purposes

Comment: Output is ok.
Since for date2 you not doing DateFormat .format(date2), you are just parsing it.
But for date your formatting it to a given format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.util.Date format conversion yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct. You are creating `date2` by parsing the date in string with the `DateFormat`. But when you print `date2`, you are not printing it with `dateFormat.format()` and hence the date is printed in its default format.

Try `System.out.println("date2:"+dateFormat.format(date2));`

Answer (score 0):

format() will return you string of date in your desired format.

```
Date Object ---------->SDF Fomatter------>Formatted date in String
```

parse() accept the date in string format (your customize format) and return you Date Object

```
Formatted String date ------>SDF parse----->Date object
```

Wanna check, print it's value:

```
dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse("01/01/2014 10:45:01"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have parsed it using dateformat, But you need to format it to get desired output.

System.out.println(("date2:"+dateFormat.format(date2)));

Answer (score 0):

Did you try dateFormat.parse("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); ?

Comment: You can also try new Date().getTime (); Why you don`t format the new date also?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
System.out.println(("date2:"+date2));
```

Implicitly calls the `toString()` method on the `date2` parameter. As `Date` has overridden the `toString()` method it inherits from `Object`, it is that method that dictates the format of the output. The Javadoc for `Date#toString()` states:

> Converts this `Date` object to a `String` of the form:
>   `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Which matches what you're seeing in your output. In order to get the output that you were expecting, you would need to do the following instead:

```
System.out.println(("date2:" + dateFormat.format(date2)));
```

`Date` objects don't have a format associated with them. They're a dumb object that doesn't need to know about any display formatting details, as they aren't relevant to the date itself.