# How we can convert yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz in Java?

Tags: java

Can anybody let me know,how we can convert date in `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS` format to date in  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz` in Java,where in both input and output dates should be Strings.

I have used apache `DateFormatUtils` but that does not give milliseconds in the output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java

Comment: [java.util.Date format conversion yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18480633) ... just replaces the formats and do more research next time.

Comment: String date = "2016-01-12-17.04.14.470000";
  String output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:sssZ").format(date);
  System.out.println(output);                                                              This gives me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: @chenchuck and Tom - This Question asks about six digits of fractional second (microseconds) which raises a extra level of complexity over the possible duplicate Questions you linked. I would say this is not a dup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Java 8+

You could also use the newer [Time API in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), something like...

```
String formatIn = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS";
String formatOut = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz";

String valueIn = "2016-01-19-09.55.00.000000";

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(valueIn, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatIn));
System.out.println("< " + ldt);

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault());        
String out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatOut).format(zdt);
System.out.println("> " + out);
```

Which outputs...

```
< 2016-01-19T09:55
> 2016-01-19T09:55:00.000AEDT
```

This makes you far more responsible for managing the time zones which might be a better solution generally

And because converting between time zones in the Java 8 API gives me a headache (lack of experience :P)

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(valueIn, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatIn));
System.out.println("< " + ldt);

ZonedDateTime here = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println("here " + here);

ZonedDateTime there = here.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
System.out.println("there " + there);
String out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatOut).format(there);
System.out.println("> " + out);
```

Which outputs...

```
< 2016-01-19T09:55
here 2016-01-19T09:55+11:00[Australia/Sydney]
there 2016-01-18T22:55Z[GMT]
> 2016-01-18T22:55:00.000GMT
```

FYI: I think your input is using nano/micro seconds and not milliseconds (there's only 1000 milliseconds in a second).  `SimpleDateFormat` does not support nano/micro seconds, but [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) does, you'd have to use the `n` pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.nnnnnn` for example

## Java 7 and below

The basic answer is, use a `SimpleDateFormat`....

```
String formatIn = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS";
String formatOut = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz";

String valueIn = "2016-01-19-09.55.00.000000";

SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat(formatIn);
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat(formatOut);

Date dateIn = in.parse(valueIn);
System.out.println("< " + dateIn);

String valueOut = out.format(dateIn);
System.out.println("> " + valueOut);
```

Which outputs...

```
< Tue Jan 19 09:55:00 AEDT 2016
> 2016-01-19T09:55:00.000AEDT
```

The problem here is, you could be converting across different time zones, which case, you could use something like...

```
in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
dateIn = in.parse(valueIn);
System.out.println("< " + dateIn);

out.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
valueOut = out.format(dateIn);
System.out.println("> " + valueOut);
```

which outputs

```
< Tue Jan 19 20:55:00 AEDT 2016
> 2016-01-19T09:55:00.000GMT
```

or a combination of, if you want to covert to a different time zone.

But, personally, I'd use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), but that's me

Comment: Many Thanks for your detailed answer.If I want time in UTC,is this right to use......   in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));                                  out.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Comment: AFAIK, yes. You might want to read the documentation for `DateFormat`, but that's the gist

Comment: Important to note that the old java.util.Date cannot handle those six digits in the fraction of second (microsecond). That class can handle only three digits, for millisecond resolution. The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes are a *vast* improvement, supporting nine digits of fractional second (nanosecond). Use these, as suggested in the latter half of this Answer. Avoid the old classes wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
        SimpleDateFormat s1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS");
        SimpleDateFormat s2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
        Date d= s1.parse( "2015-11-11-02.01.11.000001" );
        String str= s2.format( d);
        System.out.println(str);
```

This parse the string date to a Date project using the SimpleDateFormat s1. Then it parse it to the desired form using a second SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Many Thanks.This is almost what I was looking for.The only issue is when in input milliseconds are greater than 999,time is getting added in minutes to the original minutes.Can we avoid this .Say if I have input as 2016-01-12-17.04.14.470000,can we get output like 2016-01-12T17:04:14.470+01:00

Comment: @user2603985 Short answer is no, there are only 1000 milliseconds in a second. I think you time is using nano seconds, which the `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't handle

Answer (score -2):

```
String foramt = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
String dbdate = "2021-05-19 13:13:20.247";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dbdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(foramt));
ZonedDateTime finalDateFormat = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println(finalDateFormat.toOffsetDateTime());
```