# Change date format in java from ddMMyyyy to dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: java, date-format, jformattedtextfield

I have a jformattedtextfield when i put date in this format "ddMMyyyy".
I want when lost focus jformattedtextfield,  it becames and shows "dd-mm-yyyy". How i can do this???

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: 1) add focus listener on the textfield 2) place a code in this listener which willl reformat textfield's value on every focus change with the help of SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 2):

See the below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Date date = format1.parse("05011999");
System.out.println(format2.format(date));
```