# My Logic is working fine, but seems too vague.Is there any other easy way to convert "Aug/2016" to "08/2016" in java?

Tags: java, date

Is there any other easy way to convert "**Aug/2016**" to "**08/2016**" in java?

My Logic is working fine, but seems too vague.

```
String myDate = "Aug/2016"; 
String str = myDate.split("/")[0];

Date date;
            try {
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(str);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date);
                System.out.println("##### ----- month in number  :   "  +cal.get(Calendar.MONTH+1));

                int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mnth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; 

                str = String.valueOf(mnth+"/"+year);
                System.out.println("##### ----- new selected  date  :   "  +str);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

suggestions please!...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.Date format conversion yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use SimpleDateFormat:

```
    String myDate = "Aug/2016"; 
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(parser.parse(myDate)));
```