# Get Date in Numerals (Jan 7 2017 to 1 7 2016)

Tags: android, time, datepicker

I am working with a Library slide Date Time Picker, It is giving me Date String a Jan 27 2016 02:29 PM...
But I need Jan as 1, Feb as 2..etc I want Jan 27 2016 2:39PM as 1 27 2016 02:39PM

```
 private SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa");
  private TextView mButton;

   private SlideDateTimeListener listener = new SlideDateTimeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateTimeSet(Date date)
    {
        dateAndTime = mFormatter.format(date);
        mButton.setText(mFormatter.format(date));
    }

    // Optional cancel listener
    @Override
    public void onDateTimeCancel()
    {
        Toast.makeText(PutCredentials.this,
                "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: See @darshakat Ans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy hh:mm aa")`  instead of `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa")`