# How to convert String to Date with a specific format in java

Tags: java, date

I have a requirement to convert String to Date (in dd-MM-yyyy format). But dateformat.parse gives the format with seconds. I need to convert the String date to Date in the same format as mentioned above.

Comment: The Date class itself has no format. It is just a data type representing a specific date. If you want to output that date in a specific way you always have to convert it to String with a SimpleDateFormatter or something similar.

Comment: Can you please post your code? This sentence "But dateformat.parse gives the format with seconds." indicates you might have misunderstood what DateFormat is about. DateFormat.parse() gives you a Date, not a format.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
         String dateInString = "07-06-2013";

         try {

             Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
             System.out.println(date);
 

         } catch (ParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

Comment: I tried as above, but parsing gives in a format with seconds, I needed a date object which shows the format as 'dd-MM-yyyy'

Comment: Possible duplicates of [Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java/12576219#12576219) and [java.util.Date format conversion yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy/18480709#18480709) and probably a thousand others

Comment: @ananya0208 You are still misunderstanding the whole thing. If you want to output a Date object in a specific way you need to format that date for example with the SimpleDateFormat.format method. What you are currenctly doing is just calling the toString method of the Date class , which will always output the date in a fixed way.

Comment: *"I tried as above, but parsing gives in a format with seconds, I needed a date object which shows the format as 'dd-MM-yyyy'"* - `Date` is a container for the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, it DOES NOT have a concept of format.  Instead you use a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the value to a (in this case) `LocalDateTime` value and back again to a `String`, this is how the system works

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Date` will always contain both date a nd time information, since it represents an *instant in time*.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ParsingDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
            DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date d;
            try {
                d = fmt.parse("04-12-2019");
                System.out.println(d);  // Wed Dec 04 00:00:00 CET 2019
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }
}
```

As you can see, hours, minutes, seconds and millis get all set to 0.

If you later want to output the date in string format, you need to use the `DateFormat#format(Date)` method:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ParsingDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(d);  // Wed Dec 04 11:24:35 CET 2019
        System.out.println(fmt.format(d)); // 04-12-2019
    }
}
```

If you'd rather store only date information, you could use the `java.time` package and make use of `LocalDate`.
`LocalDate` stores only date information, since it does not represent an *instant*, rather a triple of year, month and date.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ParsingLocalDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse("04-12-2019", fmt);
        System.out.println(d);  // 2019-12-04
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are considered effectively deprecated in favour of the `java.time` APIs (or the ThreeTen backport if you're still stuck on earlier versions of Java)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to use time of day or time zone, you can parse it by  `LocalDate`.

```
String str = "01-01-2000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

Note that for day *and time* people most of the time would want a ZonedDateTime rather than a LocalDateTime. The name is counter-intuitive; the Local in both `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` means any locality in general rather than a specific time zone.

Comment: Please, for the love of every ones sanity, use the new `java.time` APIs instead

Comment: Thanks, for your comment. I change the question. Is it correct now?

Comment: I'd remove the reference to `SimpleDateFormat`, even if you're not using Java 8+, you can make use of the ThreeTen back port, which ports the `java.time` API for earlier versions of Java ... I'm been picky, but the community generally agrees, the old date/time APIs need to be buried ;)

Comment: I am correcting the code into using `LocalDate`. With `LocalDateTIme` I got `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01-01-2000' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2000-01-01 of type java.time.format.Parsed`.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages, date/time types are simply containers for the amount of time which has passed from a given point in time. They don’t have a format.

In the case of Java (AFAIR), time is measured in milliseconds since the Unix Epoch.

Since it's 2019, there is no excuse not to making use of the `java.time` APIs (or the [ThreeTen backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)) and you should avoid using the, now effectively deprecated, older APIs

## Parse String to `LocalDate`

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("08-03-1972", inputFormatter);
```

## Format `LocalDate` to desired format

```
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd EEE MMM yyyy");
String value = localDate.format(outputFormatter);
System.out.println(value);
```

which outputs

```
08 Wed. Mar. 1972
```